# Emulating the list.insert() method as a subclass of Python's list

Tags: python, list, subclassing

I'm trying to build a class that inherits methods from Python's list, but also does some additional things on top... it's probably easier just to show code at this point...

```
class Host(object):
    """Emulate a virtual host attached to a physical interface"""
    def __init__(self):
    # Insert class properties here...
    pass

class HostList(list):
    """A container for managing lists of hosts"""
    def __init__(self):
        self = []

    def append(self, hostobj): 
        """append to the list...""" 
        if hostobj.__class__.__name__ == 'Host': 
            self.insert(len(self), hostobj)
        else:
            _classname = hostobj.__class__.__name__
            raise RuntimeError, "Cannot append a '%s' object to a HostList" % _classname
```

My problem is this... if I want to perform the same kind of object admission tests on `insert()` as I did on `append()`, I can't find a way to code the new methods without to  sacrificing support for one list expansion method (i.e. `list.append()`, `list.insert()`, or `list.extend()`).  If I try to support them all, I wind up with recursive loops.  What is the best way around this problem?

Edit... please find my [final answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76243900/667301), based on [Nick's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5590612/667301) below...

Comment: `self = []` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `super(HostList, self).__init__(self)` would do the trick. What your code does is reassign the (argument) variable `self` to `[]`.

Comment: `__getitem__` will return a list object if a slice is specified.  You could change the initializer to `__init__(self, l = None)` that will use a list if provided.  Then in `__getitem__`, if ii is a slice object, then return `HostList(self._list[ii])`

Comment: Also, you don't necessarily have to define the `append()` method, as `MutableSequence` already does that for you, provided you have defined the `insert()` method (check http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/_collections_abc.py#l711 for more info).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can possibly avoid it, don't inherit from builtin classes. (You *can*, but that doesn't mean you *should* without a really compelling reason)

Those classes are optimised for speed, and that makes inheriting from them correctly quite tedious, since you end up having to override almost everything.

Inheriting from `collections.MutableSequence` instead lets you implement just a few essential methods, and get a robust fully featured implementation of the sequence API, without all the quirks and caveats that come with inheriting from `list`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) to check your objects to see if they're instances of `Host`, and use [`super`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) (e.g. `super(HostList, self).insert(...)`) to use the functionality of `list`, rather than reimplementing it yourself.

You should end up with something like:

```
def append(self, obj): 
    """append to the list..."""
    if not isinstance(obj, Host):
        raise RuntimeError, "Cannot append a '%s' object to a HostList" % obj.__class__.__name__
    super(HostList, self).append(obj)
```

Comment: Even better, define a static method `as_host(x)` that returns `x` if it's a host, else throws the appropriate exception. Then the `super` calls become one-liners.

Answer (score 2):

Unless if there's a compelling reason to have your HostList container completely support the mutable container interface, I suggest using a has-a model rather than is-a.  You'll have the extra burden of ensuring type consistency with operations such as slicing (return a HostList container rather than a list).

Answer (score 0):

You could call `list`'s method from your method, with `super()`.  That way you don't need to kludge it with the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I used `collections.MutableSequence` instead of subclassing Python's list()**

The resulting code... posting here in case, it helps someone...

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

class MyList(MutableSequence):
    """
    An extensive user-defined wrapper around list objects.

    Inspiration:
        https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/208a7e957b812ad3b3733791845447677a704f3e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1174https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/208a7e957b812ad3b3733791845447677a704f3e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1174
    """

    def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        self.data = []
        if initlist is not None:
            if isinstance(initlist, list):
                self.data[:] = initlist

            elif isinstance(initlist, MyList):
                self.data[:] = initlist.data[:]

            else:
                self.data = list(initlist)

    def __repr__(self):
        return """<{} data: {}>""".format(self.__class__.__name__, repr(self.data))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data < self.__cast(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.data <= self.__cast(other)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.data == self.__cast(other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.data > self.__cast(other)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.data >= self.__cast(other)

    def __cast(self, other):
        return other.data if isinstance(other, MyList) else other

    def __contains__(self, value):
        return value in self.data

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return self.__class__(self.data[idx])
        else:
            return self.data[idx]

    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        # optional: self._acl_check(val)
        self.data[idx] = value

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        del self.data[idx]

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            return self.__class__(self.data + other.data)

        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            return self.__class__(self.data + other)

        return self.__class__(self.data + list(other))

    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            return self.__class__(other.data + self.data)

        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            return self.__class__(other + self.data)

        return self.__class__(list(other) + self.data)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            self.data += other.data

        elif isinstance(other, type(self.data)):
            self.data += other

        else:
            self.data += list(other)

        return self

    def __mul__(self, nn):
        return self.__class__(self.data * nn)

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def __imul__(self, nn):
        self.data *= nn
        return self

    def __copy__(self):
        inst = self.__class__.__new__(self.__class__)
        inst.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)

        # Create a copy and avoid triggering descriptors
        inst.__dict__["data"] = self.__dict__["data"][:]

        return inst

    def append(self, value):
        self.data.append(value)

    def insert(self, idx, value):
        self.data.insert(idx, value)

    def pop(self, idx=-1):
        return self.data.pop(idx)

    def remove(self, value):
        self.data.remove(value)

    def clear(self):
        self.data.clear()

    def copy(self):
        return self.__class__(self)

    def count(self, value):
        return self.data.count(value)

    def index(self, idx, *args):
        return self.data.index(idx, *args)

    def reverse(self):
        self.data.reverse()

    def sort(self, /, *args, **kwds):
        self.data.sort(*args, **kwds)

    def extend(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyList):
            self.data.extend(other.data)

        else:
            self.data.extend(other)
```